# Xamarin.Android - Cannot Change Access Modifiers when Overriding Public Inherited Member Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, xamarin

I've created the following fragment in my Xamarin.Android solution:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Util;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using MvvmCross.Binding.Droid.Views;
using MvvmCross.Binding.Droid.BindingContext;

using ActiveNomad.Droid.Models;
using ActiveNomad.Droid.Settings;
using Android.Support.V4.App;
using MvvmCross.Droid.ViewModels;

namespace ActiveNomad.Droid.Views
{
[Register("activenomad.droid.views.adpagefragment")]
public class AdPageFragment : Fragment
{
    ImageView sponsorImageView;
    VideoView videoView;

    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);

    }

    protected override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        base.OnCreateView (inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        ActiveNomadSettings settings = SettingsManager.Instance.GetSettings ();

        sponsorImageView.FindViewById<ImageView> (Resource.Id.sponsorlogo);
        Android.Net.Uri imgUri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse (settings.SponsorImagePath);
        sponsorImageView.SetImageURI (imgUri);

        videoView.FindViewById<VideoView> (Resource.Id.AdVideo);
        Android.Net.Uri vidUri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse (settings.AdPageVideoPath);
        videoView.SetVideoURI (vidUri);
        videoView.Start ();

        return inflater.Inflate (Resource.Layout.AdPageView, container, true);

    }


  }
}
```

My Activity is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.Support.V4.App;
using ActiveNomad.Droid.Views;

namespace ActiveNomad
{
[Activity (Label = "AdPageActivity")]           
public class AdPageActivity : FragmentActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);

        var ad = new AdPageFragment{Arguments = new Bundle()};
        var fragmentTransaction = SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction ();
        fragmentTransaction.Add (Android.Resource.Id.Content, ad);
        fragmentTransaction.Commit ();
    }
 }
}
```

I changed the fragment such that `OnCreateView` is now a public override.  However, a new error is thrown:

```
  Error:  error: class adpagefragment is public, should be declared in   
  a file named adpagefragment.java
```

Xamarin Studio opens the java file but am unsure whether this is system generated, and if it should be modified.  How should this issue be resolved?

Comment: That is really another question but my guess would be it has an issue with the `Register` attribute you are using. Try `[Register("AdPageFragment")]` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the `OnCreateView` method from `protected` to `public`. It is `public` on the `Fragment` and as mentioned in the error message you cannot change the access modifier to `protected`.

```
public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
       Bundle savedInstanceState)
```